# No trailing slash in sitemap links after using docpad generate --env static

Tags: docpad

I'm using docpad-plugin-sitemap@2.2.0 and docpad-plugin-cleanurls@2.6.2.

After docpad generate --env static, the links in sitemap.xml hasn't got a trailing slash:

```
<loc>http://www.example.org/contact</loc>
```

This cause a 301 redirect to

```
http://www.example.org/contact/
```

Is this a configuration issue or does docpad-plugin-sitemap need a "static" block?

Comment: I assert that <%= document.url %> from <% for document in @getCollection('pages').toJSON(): %> misses the trailing slash, too. So i append it manually <a href="<%= document.url %>/"  property="dc:title">

Answer (score 0):

Looked up the wrong documentation at docpad-plugin-sitemap. The correct one for [trailingSlashes](https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-cleanurls/#trailingslashes) is [docpad-plugin-cleanurls](https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-cleanurls/#usageconfigure).